# How to sanitize an input from evaluateJavascript

Tags: android

I got a message from the Google Play Console saying that

> Your app includes a WebView that is vulnerable to cross app scripting. Please see this Google Help Center article for details. Vulnerable classes: com.company.main.company.MainActivity->onCreate

The error points me to [this document](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9084685) on how to fix the issue

It gives me 2 options. I cannot use Option 1 because it kills my app when changing `android:exported=false`

So I am stuck with option 2. One of the things it says is to

> Ensure that parameters to evaluateJavascript are always trusted. Calling evaluateJavascript using unsanitized input from untrusted Intents lets attackers execute harmful scripts in the affected WebView.

The way I am using [evaluateJavascript](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()) in my webView is I am getting the HTML of a div with id `user_id_firebase` to determine the apps state of whether the user has logged out of my app or they are logged on. Then with the firebase ID I can update my DB with the users/apps token for notifications.

**Code**

```
             webView.evaluateJavascript(
                        "(function() { return (document.getElementById('user_id_firebase').innerHTML); })();",
                        new ValueCallback<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                                html = html.replaceAll("[\"]+", "");
                                StringTokenizer currentString = new StringTokenizer(html, "|");
                                final String first = currentString.nextToken().trim();
                                final String second = currentString.nextToken().trim();
                                // Write a message to the database
                                database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                                FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MainActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                                        String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
                                        if (first.equals("gone")) {
                                            database.child("users").child(second).child("android").child(getMacAddr()).removeValue();
                                        } else if (first.equals("none")) {
                                            database.child("users").child(second).child("android").child(getMacAddr()).removeValue();
                                        } else if (first.equals("active")) {
                                            database.child("users").child(second).child("android").child(getMacAddr()).setValue(newToken);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });
```

Because I am getting the HTML of that div from `document.getElementById` I am assuming it is referring to this input which is what I believe I need to sanitize.

How do I sanitize this input to make the Google Gods happy? I have seen there are several ways to do this, but is there a specific way I need to do it that will get my app to be approved once again?

Comment: did you find out ?

Comment: @micaball I did not unfortunately, I ended up leaving javascript all together and used a different solution.

Comment: what was your alternative solution in this situation? @CesarBielich